# How to format concatenated list output - python

Tags: python, list, format

I am using pyexcel to try to filter an excel file for certain values, but I can't figure out how to format my functions output.

I need to output cell values in the form [x,y] for pyexcel to read the data, currently my output is coming out as [x, y], and the space before the y value makes it so pyexcel crashes.

Saw some questions answered using the % string format method, but this has no effect for my script.

This is what I currently have, crash location identified with <---:

```
import pyexcel as pe

sheet = pe.get_sheet(file_name="foo.xlsx") 

print sheet #displays excel file

#these are accepted ways to output a cell value
#sheet[1,2], "numeric" 
#sheet['B1'], "alphanumeric"

list_rows = list(range(11))   #Max Row Value +1 as upper bound
list_columns = list(range(4))    #Max Column Value +1 as upper bound

def Scroller(max_row,max_column):
  r = 0
  while r <= (len(list_rows)-1):
    c = 0
    while c <= (len(list_columns)-1):
      index = [list_rows[r],list_columns[c]]
      print "%s" % index
      print sheet[index]  <------
      c += 1
    r += 1

Scroller((len(list_rows)-1),(len(list_columns)-1))
```

While this iterates correctly to hit all cell values, its output has a space like:

```
[0, 0]
[0, 1]
[0, 2] ... etc.
```

I need:

```
[0,0]
[0,1]
[0,2] ... etc.
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Try `print '[{0},{1}]'.format(sheet[index][0], sheet[index][1])` instead of `print sheet[index]`

Comment: no dice, sadly, I am running python 2.7, so not sure if the formatting is off or not, but didn't work. thanks for the quick reply though!

Comment: Python 2.7 is very rapidly approaching [end of life](https://pythonclock.org/).  Is there a good reason for you not to use Python3 ?

Comment: Or, try `print str(sheet[index]).replace(' ', '')`

Comment: Doubt its related to string formatting, looks like your passing a list to `sheet`

Comment: @Symbal I'm baffled at why that wouldn't work..., are you sure `sheet[index]` is doing what you want it to do, as you're passing a list into it..

Comment: I'm going to go on a limb, I think the output you actually have is from `print '%s' % index` and not `print sheet[index]`, (if you want to be printing the value of the cell in Excel doing `sheet[i][j]` makes more sense to me..), so then try `print '[{0}, {1}]'.format(index[0], index[1])` ..that is, if my 'limb thinking' is correct.

Comment: @John1024 just used to the syntax haha no real profound reason haha

Comment: @Max yeah, I realized the % notation is just formatting the output... the real formatting/work needs to be done to the actual `index` variable, not the print statement below it... print aside, the way the pyexcel module works needs it to be [x,y]... so regardless of how it is being output for my unnecessary visual happiness, the internal state (?) needs to be in that format. I will give these a go and the answer below and report back when I can, thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Caveat: I've never used pyexcel as I prefer CSV modules...**

No experience with this module, but given your syntax, couple of thoughts here:

1. `sheet` is some object that can be accessed via the `__getitem__()` method
2. To access something in `sheet` its either `sheet[row, col]` or `sheet['A#']`
3. Your saying that `sheet[1, 2]` will crash due to the space in `[1, 2]`

Given these constraints, lets examine what you've posted. First, lets start with your sample outputs:

```
print "%s" % index
# [0, 0]
# [0, 1]
# [0, 2] ... etc.
```

Well this tells me that `index` is of type `list` containing ints, which makes sense given the prior line:

```
index = [list_rows[r],list_columns[c]]
```

Then you say your program crashes at the following line:

```
print sheet[index]  <------
```

But you said `sheet` has to be indexed by the constraints in Item 2,lets look at what you're doing:

```
index = [list_rows[r],list_columns[c]]
# For example, the first one is [0, 0]
# Currently, index = [0, 0]
print "%s" % index # Which prints index as a string
print sheet[index] # You're doing sheet[[0, 0]]
# Wait, you broke Item 2 constraints!
```

So, give the following a try:

1. `print sheet[index[0], [index[1]]` or...
2. `print sheet[*index]` as its a bit cleaner

Frankly you can reduce some code:

```
def Scroller(max_row,max_column):
  r = 0
  while r <= (len(list_rows)-1):
    c = 0
    while c <= (len(list_columns)-1):
      print sheet[list_rows[r],list_columns[c]]
      c += 1
    r += 1
```

Some reading on string formatting however:

- Outdated [*printf*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting) style
- The [str.format()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) method
- Newer [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals)

Comment: Well, definitely a lesson learned... I never even fact check the `sheet` naming convention, you nailed it with the "print sheet[index] # You're doing sheet[[0, 0]]" I was setting `index` to [[0, 0]]... silly mistake, and weird that when `print index` is called it truncated the extra [ ]'s so I didn't actually know that it was like that... fixed the simple error, and thanks to you and all the others for the insight and help!

Comment: @Symbal The `print index` never truncated anything. The name `index` is `[0, 0]`, when you use `sheet[index]` you're _adding_ the `[ ]` operator for access to `sheet`.